# Safari still able to read deleted Cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, safari, mobile-safari

I'm encountering a peculiar problem in Safari that isn't happening in Edge. I am setting a Cookie for my web app in Python after logging into GitHub/Discord. The cookie has some non-sensitive user information used to display the user's name and avatar in the menu bar.

This all works just fine. When pressing Log Out, the Cookies are gone from the Inspector. Great. However, JS is still able to read this deleted Cookie, no matter how often I refresh.

```
  function changeLoginButton() {
    cookie_data = JSON.parse(checkCookie("my-cookie"))
    try {
      if (cookie_data) {
        if (cookie_data.avatar_url) {
            console.log("hitting avatar url");
            console.log(cookie_data.avatar_url);
            document.getElementById("logout_button_icon").src = cookie_data.avatar_url;
        }
     }
  }
```

Log after clearing cookies:

```
[Log] hitting avatar url (login-status.js, line 35)
[Log] https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/REDACTED?v=4 (login-status.js, line 36)
```

What's even more strange is that forcefully trying to set the variable `cookie_data` to nothing when pressing log out, it still outputs the entire Cookie content into the terminal if I print it after refreshing. Before the refresh it does print an empty `cookie_data`.

```
cookie_data = "{}"
console.log("Hitting logout button");
console.log(cookie_data);
```

Safari - Logged in

```
hitting avatar url
login-status.js:36 https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/REDACTED?v=4
> cookie_data
{id: "REDACTED", username: "REDACTED", name: "REDACTED", avatar_url: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/REDACTED?v=4"}
```

Safari - Cookies cleared (pseudo logged in)

```
hitting avatar url
login-status.js:36 https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/REDACTED?v=4
> cookie_data
{id: "REDACTED", username: "REDACTED", name: "REDACTED", avatar_url: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/REDACTED?v=4"}
```

Edge - Logged in:

```
hitting avatar url
login-status.js:36 https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/REDACTED?v=4
> cookie_data
{id: "REDACTED", username: "REDACTED", name: "REDACTED", avatar_url: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/REDACTED?v=4"}
```

Edge - Logged out:

```
> cookie_data
null
```

This manifests on both desktop and mobile Safari. On mobile Safari, this is cleared by switching out of the Safari app into another app. No amount of refreshing fixes it (same behavior on desktop)

Seems like it's stored in memory somehow? How do I clear this? If I hit my API that handles the OAuth, it shows that I am indeed logged out:

```
{"msg":"User is not logged in.","rc":"notloggedin"}
```

A possible workaround is that I retrieve this information from my API directly, but I am trying to reduce unnecessary calls to it, which retrieving a static username and avatar per refresh definitely is.

Comment: Sounds like a cache issue. Are you sending them a new page with status 200 or is using it cached with 304?

Comment: Were are you clearing the cookie, doing `cookie_data = "{}"` will not clear any cookies.

Comment: @Keith I am clearing it in my API call for logouts. (Python) I also added a delete cookie to JS (kind of double) to no avail. My browser storage shows no cookies after the delete. I set the cookie_data var to see if I could empty the var the cookie loads into, not to delete the cookie. The only mystery here is why Safari is weird about it and why switching apps on mobile makes it “work”. It seems like it is stored in memory.